# ng-change not working with asynchronous controller logic

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework, controller, angularjs-ng-change

So I have a controller with a couple of asynchronous .then functions. In the end I catch them all with a $q.all() function to continue my synchronous work. Now I have a select with dynamic options:

```
 <select ng-model="data.selectedUser" ng-change="changeList()" ng-options="user as user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname for user in users">
    <option value="">Select a user...</option>
  </select>
```

With ng-change I want to get the selected user in my controller, so I call changeList(). In the changeList function I do some simple alerts which do not trigger. When I do the test alert first in the controller it even freezes at choosing an option.

In my $q.all() function:

```
    $q.all(promises).then(function () {
          users = UserService.getUsers();
          $scope.users = users;
          $scope.data.selectedUser = {};

          $scope.changeList = function () {
            var chosenUser = $scope.data.selectedUser;
            alert(chosenUser.firstname);
            alert('test');
          };

        }, function () {
          alert('Failed');
        });
```

The alerts do nothing, I also tried putting the changeList function out of the $q.all function in the bottom of the controller. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
user is already defined and all of that is working. It is purely about why the ng-change is not working. It is also tested without emptying the selectedUser scope first.

Comment: first of all, you are resetting $scope.data.selectedUser = {}; to an empty object, second (I don't know if that's by purpose) you are not using the var keyword on users ( user = UserService....,  not var user = Userservice....

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that user is already defined all of that is already working. Its purely about the changeList problem. Also the scope reset is because normally it will not work if I dont define it empty first. But also tested without that and still the problem persists

Comment: Yes but you have to define $scope.data.selectedUser outside your function. And I don't understand why $scope.changeList is in your q.all resultblock

Comment: When I do that for example at the start of the controller my selectlist is somehow empty

Comment: And it is in the $q method because I have tried it outside of it and inside.

Comment: Do $scope.changeList = function (){alert('triggered'); outside the q.all block and it should trigger when you select a user

Comment: I tried that now, when I select an option it freezes.

Comment: comment the the q.all out and maybe other functions untill it does work and debug from there

Comment: Thanks for your time I will!

Comment: The answer by Oliver indicates that ng-change doesn't work on a select (i didnt know that). So try his solution. (dont put his code in the q.all block)

Comment: Well what I did now was comment all my code out except users and the scope watch, still it does not work properly so the asynchronous functions arent the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The it does not look like ng-change works on a select.  You can have a look at this js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fc984j9b/

Instead of using the ng-change to fire the event I used a $watch on the ng-model of the select to trigger a function instead, in your case it would be:

```
$scope.$watch("data.selectedUser", function(){
     $scope.changeList();
});
```

I hope hat helps

Best Regards

Oliver

Comment: I tried that and somehow it only triggers once the view is loaded, but when I change options it does not trigger anymore something else must be wrong with my code then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle that uses your code and does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/A_Sambres/2kwhw0dw/1/

The things there that must be different from your code are the users object

```
  users = [{"firstname":"Adrien","lastname":"Foo"}, ...{"firstname":"Thing2","lastname":"Foo"}];
```

, and the initialization of the data object.

```
 $scope.data = {selectedUser : {}};
```

So I guess you could inspect the differences between this code and yours to spot what goes wrong.
It may be the users object that has not the right structure, or the $scope.data that is not correctly declared in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Adrien, will check it out!